Sql string concatenation is always bad?
At university, we learned, and I also read in many places, that you should NEVER concatenate SQL strings. Yes, I know it's because of SQL injection, and I am aware of that.
However, what if the string you want to concatenate is only accessible in the code? So it is NOT user input and has nothing to do with it.
For example, I have a Character table with a character_id field. This Character has many attributes, so the character_id appears in many other tables as a foreign key. When I create a row in the Character table, I need to create rows in other tables where it appears as a foreign key.
To do this, I would need to write SQL statements one by one, since "you should NEVER use concatenation." However, a valid function here would be:
public void insertAttribute(String attributeTable, int characterId) {
String sql = "INSERT INTO "+attributeTable+" (character_id) VALUES (?)";
// execute
}

This could be called with any attributeTable, as long as the attributeTable string is not requested from the user, but only used in concatenation to shorten the code.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

You should NEVER concatenate user input.

You can do concatenation if the source is guaranteed to be safe, but there's really no reason to do that either. Using prepared statements isn't any more effort, is arguably more readable, and handles escaping if attributeTable happens to be a reserved word. And there's no risk of forgetting to change it if attributeTable at some point later does start to come from an untrusted source.

Read about SQL Injection attacks to understand the issue: https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection. The issue is not concatenation but concatenating user inputs or variables that could be tampered with.

@GuyIncognito You can't bind a table name in a prepared statement. At least not in a select or insert. You could do it with a stored procedure and a CallableStatement. But I'm not sure it's worth it.

When you need to do something like "INSERT INTO "+attributeTable+" it means your database structure is wrong. Tables must be linked by values, not names

@YourCommonSense
my database looks like something like this:
create table character
(
id serial
constraint character_id
primary key,
name varchar(255) not null,
profession varchar(255),
.....
);
And here is one attribute table of many:
create table body_skill
(
character_id integer
constraint body_skill_id
references character,
physique integer default 0,
endurance integer default 0
);
Whats wrong with this? Why is it wrong structure?

@GuyIncognito
Iam not sure how prepared statements solve would be better. Can you give me an example?

The problem of the question cannot be solved with a prepared statement, because you can only parametrize values, not object names like a table name.

You can use prepared statements when inserting values instead of concatenating them, like others have said. And like Your Common Sense said, if you have many different attribute tables then your database is badly designed. Each attribute should not be a separate table.

@GuyIncognito
I can't replace a table name with a prepared statement either, so that doesn't solve anything. Iam not concatenating values, I concatenating table name. Its a big diffrence. Prepared statement cannot accep
I have more than 100 attributes. I need to separate them to other tables, because logic reasons.

Yes. that's what I said. You can use prepared statements when inserting values. You can't use them when using dynamic table names. And your "logic reasons" are flawed, the database design is wrong.

@GuyIncognito
If I store all the attributes in 1 table, the searchign and sorting will be extremely slow, and more difficult to expnad.
not to mention that the attributes are also logically separated. I tested it and it is much faster (I have a request about 5 times faster)
But you declare that the concept is flawed without knowing the purpose of the database or anything about it? Just based on 1 query?

"If I store all the attributes in 1 table, the searchign and sorting will be extremely slow, and more difficult to expnad" this is not true. Your tests are flawed (or probably you are doing selects some bizarre way). Having everything in one table should be faster.

There can be several tables, some that contain the structure of different attribute types, and some that contain the actual data. That's where the design part comes in. You have more design options than just the two that you came up with.

The act of concatenating a string is not inherently bad.  For example, while silly there is no security risk in doing this:
String sql = "INSERT INTO " + "MyTable" + " (character_id) VALUES (?)";

Expanding further, if you have a finite set of values to replace "MyTable" and you control those values, you can dynamically choose from them without presenting a security risk.
The problem comes not when concatenating strings, or even when letting users select which strings to concatenate.  The problem comes when you don't control those strings.
Any value which is user-modifiable, be it from direct user input or indirect user editing of other database values, or any other way in which users can modify the values used... Those values should not be concatenated into the SQL code.
Not because of the act of concatenation, but because of the act of treating user input as code and executing it.
As your example even demonstrates, one very common reason to do this at all is to dynamically replace schema objects (such as table names), which generally can't be done with parameters.

Note that there are other reasons to avoid dynamically concatenating strings into SQL code.  You could be missing out on performance optimizations from the database if doing this for otherwise parameter-drivable values.  You could be setting a precedent that later, less-careful developers then expand into something that is SQL-injectable.  Etc.
There can often be better approaches.  Using ORMs, using stored procedures, or just allowing the lines-of-code to be larger than you would have wanted just to keep it consistent/clear/secure.  Sometimes even just avoiding the precedent of allowing such concatenation into a large codebase is itself worth a little extra effort.

It's not only user input, but any untrusted source of content. For example, fetching data from a file or a web service call and executing it as part of your SQL statement is also a risk. We have no idea what that web service is going to respond.

If you validate the parameter then you can protect yourself from sql injection attacks
private static final Set<String> TABLE_WHITELIST = Set.of("FOO", "BAR", "BAZ");

public void insertAttribute(String table, int characterId) {
   if (!TABLE_WHITELIST.contains(table)) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Table " + table + " not allowed");
   }
   String sql = "INSERT INTO "+ table +" (character_id) VALUES (?)";
   // execute
}

